# MongoDB Possible to insert if field in another table is not null

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

E.g.

```
if(table1.customer1 != null)
then insert into table2 'customer1'
```

Can this be done in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is Two-Phase-Commit: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (in a single operation) to update a document in one collection based on value of another document (in the same or different collection).

You can do it in your application code but that's not guaranteed to be atomic.